# Copy from clipboard to array and from array to outlook subject line in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to copy the data from the clipboard then store that in an array then copy what that from the array into the outlook subject line. I'm stuck on copying the data into FROM THE ARRAY into the out outlook subject line. Here is my code.

```
 DoCmd.Minimize
    DoCmd.OpenReport " INFORMATION", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy


Btn_BundleInformation_Click_look:

   Dim LString As String
   Dim LArray() As String
   Dim OutApp As Object
   Dim OutMail As Object
   Dim olInsp As Object
   Dim wdDoc As Object
   Dim oRng As Object
   Dim olapp As Object
   Dim strsubject As String
   Dim strArray(1 To 5) As String

    Dim B As Integer

    Dim Sn As String
    Dim Rq As String
    Dim J As String
    Dim PP As String

    J = JOB#
    B = BUNDLE#
    Sn = SEGMENTNAME
    Rq = RECORDQTY
    PP = PlatformProject

   'Dim arrA As Variant

Dim strString

  'arrA = Array("BUNDLE#", "SEGMENTNAME", "RECORDQTY", "PlatformProject")

  Dim varArray() As String
varArray() = Split("BUNDLE#;CREATION DATE;BUNDLE TYPE;Spring;JOB #;PKG(s);SEGMENT NAME:COMPARED TO BUNDLE;PCR VERSION;MAPPING VERSION;OSE # & Version;RECORD QTY;Platform Project;", ";") 
    On Error Resume Next


    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    'rst.Close


   On Error GoTo 0

If Not olapp Is Nothing Then
  'Outlook is open!
  'MsgBox "Outlook is running"

Else
  'Outlook not open
  'MsgBox "Outlook is not running"

  Shell ("OUTLOOK")

End If
'end check outlook
    'open new mail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


    Dim DataObj As MsForms.DataObject
    Set DataObj = MsForms.DataObject


    On Error Resume Next

  'Get data from the clipboard.
   DataObj.GetFromClipboard

   'Get clipboard contents
   LString = DataObj.GetText
   LArray = Split(LString)


    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .BodyFormat = 3
        .TO = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""

        .subject =
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .display


    End With
   On Error GoTo 0

'Deassign all objects.
    OutApp.Session.Logoff
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    'Set rst = Nothing
    'Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: What is contents of your array? And which elements are you trying to assign it to? Subject is just one element - how big is your array? You can just use `subject = LArray(#)` if you know its location in the array (it's zero based)

Comment: @dbmitch. I just updated what the content of my array looks like. What if I want to copy some items to the subjectline?

Comment: Same info applies - except make sure to dim your array differently not `Dim varArray() As String` - just use `Dim varArray As Variant`.. So if you want to display "CREATION DATE" you refer to it as `varArray(1)` - second element in zero-based array

Comment: How is that got anything to do with copy/paste from clipboard though?

Comment: @dbmitch The data i'm trying to use has already been copied to the clipboard and it pastes in the body, so I'm trying to get some of the data and paste into the subjectline. So could i do "subject = varArray(1), varArray(4), varArray(8)" to paste in the subject from the array?

Comment: I created an answer for you with an example

Comment: be cautious about helping Becca as they will delete the question once answered.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
Dim varArray() As String   
varArray() = Split("BUNDLE#;CREATION DATE;BUNDLE TYPE;Spring;JOB #;PKG(s);SEGMENT NAME:COMPARED TO BUNDLE;PCR VERSION;MAPPING VERSION;OSE # & Version;RECORD QTY;Platform Project;", ";")
```

To This

```
Dim varArray As Variant   
varArray() = Split("BUNDLE#;CREATION DATE;BUNDLE TYPE;Spring;JOB #;PKG(s);SEGMENT NAME:COMPARED TO BUNDLE;PCR VERSION;MAPPING VERSION;OSE # & Version;RECORD QTY;Platform Project;", ";")
```

Then create the subject line by concatenating the items in your zero-based array

So if you wanted it to look like: BUNDLE# - BUNDLE TYPE - JOB#

You'd set your subject line by merging the elements you need with the concatenate operator ("&") and include whatever other text between

```
.subject = varArray(0) & " - " & varArray(2) & " - " & varArray(4)
```

Comment: @dbmitch.Thanks for your help

Comment: You bet - mark it as an naswer to complete the process - or you can update your question with added info. Glad to hear you got it figured